# Hohmann Transfer and Lagrange Point

Tags: orbital-motion, rocket-science, celestial-mechanics

I recently learned about Lagrange points and Hohmann transfer orbit concepts. I need to confirm some facts. I looked up several sites but found no answer.

1. I wanted to find whether spaceships are targeted to a Lagrange point when sent through a Hohmann orbit.
   Ex - In Earth to mars travel, will the spaceship be sent to a Sun-Mars Lagrange point in order to enter the orbit.
2. Are Lagrange points used to enter and exit orbits around planets when being slingshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the general case: when planning a Hohmann transfer the Lagrange points are irrelevant.

The only connection, I think, is when the destination orbit of a spacecraft is to actually orbit near a particular Lagrange point. Then the engine burn to ascend to the intended altitude is timed such that when the spacecraft arrives at altitude it also arrives near the intended Lagrange point. That is the most fuel efficient way to get there.

In the case of gravitational assist the spacecraft does a close fly-by. On the other hand, none of the Lagrange points associated with a planet are close to that planet. Hence the Lagrange points are irrelevant for planning gravitational assist trajectory.